# How to get a value from a JSON in Python?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I want to get the value of timestamp and value from the following JSON

```
[{'name': 'temperature', 'resolution': 900, 'location': 'Takahuhdin koulu', 'room-id': '1', 'data': {'timestamp': '2018-09-05T07:59:03.429Z', 'value': 21.400000000000002}}]
```

After json.loads I got this JSON. How can I assign a variable of the value of timestamp and convert it to mysql yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS format

I tried

```
dataJSON = json.loads(result) // dataJSON have the JSON
dataJSON['data']['timestamp']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have list of dict. Iterate it or use index.

**Ex:**

```
dataJSON  = [{'name': 'temperature', 'resolution': 900, 'location': 'Takahuhdin koulu', 'room-id': '1', 'data': {'timestamp': '2018-09-05T07:59:03.429Z', 'value': 21.400000000000002}}]
print(dataJSON[0]['data']['timestamp'])
```

---

or

```
for data in dataJSON:
    print(data['data']['timestamp'])
```

**Output:**

```
2018-09-05T07:59:03.429Z
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I change 2018-09-05T07:59:03.429Z to mysql format ?

Comment: Try: `datetime.datetime.strptime(data['data']['timestamp'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`